# Why Blob.getDataAsString return string with zero length?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, blob

One and the same json file. The same code. The random result. One time non-zero length, another time zero length. What happens?

Especially often the error appears when running on a trigger. For example, once a minute. When running from the editor, almost never.

The code worked without errors on triggers for more than a month. Errors started appearing yesterday and today.

Code runs on [Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com/home/my). You can run it too. [Download file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xrsQ_OustGDITit1QfkeYJG0Ga6bBqlS/view?usp=sharing) to Google Drive in folder `Data`. And use block `Full code`

```js
function tryParseJSON(file) {
    if (!file) return [];
    console.log('file', file.getName());
    let blob = file.getBlob();
    console.log('blob', blob.toString());
    let text = blob.getDataAsString();
    console.log('text length', text.length);
    console.log('text', text);
    try {
        return JSON.parse(text);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Не удалось перевести строку JSON в объект.', e, e.stack, 'text', text);
        return [];
    }
}
```

### Run

```js
function debug() {
  let x = Cache.read('test.json');
}
```

### Logs

```
// time 00:38:17
file test.json
blob Blob
text length 0
text 

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at tryParseJSON (Library:1966:25)
    at Object.read (Library:1888:16)
    at debug (Debug:2:22)
    at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8 text 

// time 00:37:17
file test.json
blob Blob
text length 19
text {
    "id": 1
}
```

### Full code

```
const Cache = (function () {
    const FOLDER_NAME = 'Data';
    const rootFolder = getRootFolder();

    return {
        read: read,
        write: write,
        append: append,
        clear: clear,
        copy: copy,
        remove: remove,
        rename: rename,
    };

    function read(filename) {
        return tryParseJSON(getFile(filename));
    }

    function append(filename, content, place = 'end', limit = 100000) {
        if (!content || content.length == 0) return;
        let currentContent = read(filename);
        if (place == 'begin') {
            appendNewData(content, currentContent);
        } else if (place == 'end') {
            appendNewData(currentContent, content);
        }

        function appendNewData(xData, yData) {
            Combiner.push(xData, yData);
            Selector.keepFirst(xData, limit);
            write(filename, xData);
        }
    }

    function clear(filename) {
        write(filename, []);
    }

    function write(filename, content) {
        let file = getFile(filename);
        if (!file) {
            file = createFile(filename);
        }
        file.setContent(JSON.stringify(content));
    }

    function copy(filename) {
        let file = getFile(filename);
        if (file) {
            filename = 'Copy' + formatExtension(filename.split('.')[0]);
            file.makeCopy().setName(filename);
            return filename;
        }
    }

    function remove(filename) {
        let file = getFile(filename);
        if (file) {
            file.setTrashed(true);
        }
    }

    function rename(oldFilename, newFilename) {
        let file = getFile(oldFilename);
        if (file) {
            file.setName(formatExtension(newFilename));
        }
    }

    function getFile(filename) {
        let files = getFileIterator(filename);
        if (files.hasNext()) {
            return files.next();
        }
    }

    function createFile(filename) {
        return rootFolder.createFile(formatExtension(filename), '');
    }

    function getFileIterator(filename) {
        return rootFolder.getFilesByName(formatExtension(filename));
    }

    function tryParseJSON(file) {
        if (!file) return [];
        console.log('file', file.getName());
        let blob = file.getBlob();
        console.log('blob', blob.toString());
        let text = blob.getDataAsString();
        console.log('text length', text.length);
        console.log('text', text);
        try {
            return JSON.parse(text);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Не удалось перевести строку JSON в объект.', e, e.stack, 'text', text);
            return [];
        }
    }

    function getRootFolder() {
        let folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(FOLDER_NAME);
        if (folders.hasNext()) {
            return folders.next();
        }
        return DriveApp.createFolder(FOLDER_NAME);
    }

    function formatExtension(filename) {
        if (!filename.includes('.')) {
            filename += '.json';
        }
        return filename;
    }
})();
```

[image]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, in your case, when LockService is used, what result will you obtain? As the sample script, how about `function debug() { const lock = LockService.getScriptLock(); if (lock.tryLock(5000)) {try {let x = Cache.read('test.json')}catch(e){throw new Error(e)}finally{lock.releaseLock()}} }`. About `5000`, please modify it for your actual situation. I post this as a comment because I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike suddenly appeared, suddenly disappeared. This morning, the error disappeared. I didn't change code. I think that it problem from Google.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.